# Where is the search and replace feature?

Tags: search

I want to replace the value in a field (yahoo Home) with another value for multiple contacts. The field is in the summary screen for contact types = Organization.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about "Search and Replace", but you can do the above from the "Update multiple contacts" task on the contacts returned on `Advanced Search`.

- All you need to do is add your field(I think it's `IM Screen name` in your case) to a profile (Created from Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Profiles).
- Use Search -> Advanced Search to filter and get your contacts -> Select `Update multiple contacts` on the Action dropdown.
- Select your profile where you've added the field in step 1.
- Enter the new value for the contact(You can also make use of Copy icon to copy text to all the rows) and click `Update Contacts` button.